# Will symbol size impact buffer size?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, symbology, buffer

I'm using ArcMap 10.1. I want to create buffers that represent CO2 equivalent from landfills.  I used graduated symbols to label each landfill site, based on amount on incoming waste per year.  Will the size of the symbols impact the size of my buffers? Or do buffers always measure diameter from the centroid of the point?

Comment: Have you tried testing your theory that the symbol size may matter by running the same size buffer on a point with a massive symbol and another with a tiny symbol and pulling out the Measure tool?

Answer (score 1):

Points have no size, so any buffer is measured from the centroid of the point and symbol size has nothing to do with buffering.

You can test this by creating a point and setting a small symbol and buffering by `5m`, and then changing the symbol to something very very large and buffering again by `5m`.  When you measure the diameter of the buffer polygons you will find that both polygons will be the same diameter - `10m`.